# Python формат .рус

Tags: python, django

Когда создаю проект на django, есть файлы **__init__.рус**, **wsgi.рус**.
Я их удаляю, но иногда они сами появляются опять. В чем проблема?

Comment: related: [How to avoid .pyc files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/154443/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Эти файлы содержат питоновский байт код, в который интерпретатор компилирует твой исходный код. Просто игнорируй их, добавь в `.gitignore`, чтобы не лезли в репозиторий и т.д.

Comment: спасибо понял:)

Comment: В Питоне 3, можно ещё `__pycache__/` папки в `.gitignore` добавить (с `*.py[co]` файлами).

Comment: Для PyCharm есть отличный плагин `.ignore` для генерации разных ignore файлов, в том числе для git, из готовых шаблонов для разных языков, платформ и т.п.